# Silent printing + specify non-default printer

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web-applications, printing

**Requirements**

Intranet web app needs to print jillions of receipts daily. Silent print in either Chrome or Firefox works fine --- consider this part solved.

**Fly in ointment**

So we use command line options in either chrome or firefox to enable speedy silent printing but these are regular workstations, not POS. They have regular network printers for everything but receipt printing.

In many configurations Firefox and Chrome will use the "last used printer", but this is unreliable and doesn't work in some configurations ...eg., Linux. Firefox does not honor changing the print command or even specifying print_printer either.

**Questions**

Is it possible to specify a printer on the command line:

Eg.,

```
firefox -no-remote -P webapp --print-target receipt
```

or -

```
chrome --kiosk --kiosk-printing receipt
```

Is there a plugin, extension or application that will force FF or Chrome to ignore the system default printer for a certain profile, ( or site ) and use a specified printer?

Is there a greasemonkey script to do this?

We can't rely on Firefox or Chrome to use the "last used printer" ...sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. Has anyone come up with a hackish shell script to do this ...as you can tell I'm at wits end and desperate. <s>We would pay for this</s> [ UPDATE: you are too late for $$ at this point, I beat you to the punch ].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/edabg/jsprintsetup extension for FF.

Among the options are: setSilentPrint, setPrintersList - Returns comma separated list of available printers, setPrinter - Set current printer, getPrinter - Returns currently selected printer, etc.

Comment: This works perfectly and is less a hassle than my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

I <s>answered the question</s> **solved the problem** here:

https://superuser.com/questions/406857/debian-firefox-or-iceweasel-default-printer-for-pos-station-web-application

Used a separate account, some sudo magic and a shared folder.

Both submitted questions are different ways of looking at the problem -- but through the lens of "must use browser features" -- with slightly different assumptions about possible solutions. So not entirely duplicated, in other words.

One is: can I specify an app level printer default?

Another is: can I tell a browser instance to use a specific printer via cli option?

To both, the answer is either **no** , or shrouded in SEO tainted Google results.